# .NET MVC - Map text from TextBoxFor to an Array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My model is set up so the controller can deliver a Json response of data from user input.  The 'rgba' property of my model is an array of ints.  If a user enters text of say '255, 0, 0, 1' into the TextBoxFor for 'rgba', the text is not mapping into an array (which I thought was supposed to happen automagically). Instead, int[0] is what makes it to the controller.

I've tried all the potential solutions I could find on here, including passing a FormCollection object to controller.  I've tried to get the TextBoxFor value using JS/jQuery and manipulate the data, but can't figure out how to pass the manipulated data back to the model (this seems less than ideal, like there should be an easy way to do this in .Net).

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult NewColor()
    {
        Rootobject newColor = new Rootobject();

        return View(newColor);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult NewColor(Rootobject color)
    {

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(color);

        return Json(json);

    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Color[] colors { get; set; }
}

public class Color
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Code code { get; set; }
}

public class Code
{
    public int[] rgba { get; set; }
    public string hex { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model WebAppPlayground.Models.Rootobject

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "New Color";
}

<style>
    input:focus {
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    input {
        padding: 2px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-style: ridge;
    }
</style>

<h2>New Color</h2>

<h4>Color</h4>
<hr />
<center>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("NewColor", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
    {
        <table style="border-collapse:separate; border-spacing: 5px 5px">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="form-group" for="Color">
                    <td>Color</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.colors[0].color)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="form-group">
                    <td class="">Category</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.colors[0].category)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="form-group">
                    <td class="">Type</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.colors[0].type)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="form-group">
                    <td class="">rgba</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.colors[0].code.rgba, new { id = "rgba"})</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="form-group">
                    <td class="">Hex</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.colors[0].code.hex)</td>
                </tr>


            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </div>
</center>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

I would like my Controller to receive an array of Int's via `rgba` TextBoxFor where user enters text eg `255, 0, 0, 1`.

I think there is something (obvious) I am overlooking or not understanding.

---

****Updated controller post method to remove added 'rgba_str' prop per @i_ll_be_back 's answer and deliver desired Json data:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult NewColor(Rootobject color)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(color);

            JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);

            JObject code = (JObject)jsonObject["colors"][0]["code"];

            code.Property("rgba_str").Remove();

            return Json(jsonObject);
        }
```

Comment: You will need a custom `ModelBinder` class for this. Without that, MVC will not understand that a certain formatted string (that it has no knowledge of) needs to be (1) split at commas and (2) each part converted to `int`. You can find lots of ModelBinder tutorials on e.g. [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=mvc+custom+model+binder).

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to use @i_ll_be_back 's model to get desired my desired result.  I will research this later today and update for which solution is best.

Comment: That can also work, but only a ModelBinder has the advantage that it can integrate seamlessly with `ModelState.IsValid` and `Html.ValidationMessageFor` / `Html.ValidationSummary`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following reshaping the Code class in the following:

```
public class Code
{
    public int[] rgba { get; set; }
    public string rgba_str
    {
        get
        {
            var res = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < rgba.Length; i++) {
                res += rgba[i] + (i != rgba.Length - 1 ? "," : "");
            }
            return res;
        }
        set
        {
            var strArray = value.Split(',');
            rgba = new int[strArray.Length];
            for(int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++) {
                rgba[i] = int.Parse(strArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    public string hex { get; set; }
}
```

Now bind the TextBoxFor with the rgba_str field

Comment: I was able to get the proper Json delivered by using the above model, then updating my post controller to remove the added string rgba_str prop... see updated OP for new controller code.